# How do Gregtech machines explode from rain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

So I built a roof of leaves for my one house right? (I wanted to be different)

Then it rained and I realized the leaves drip water when it rains, so I got worried about when I have machines in the house because Gregtech Machines supposedly explode from rain.

I went into creative mode to test out if leaf roofs work or not. I put some greg tech machines out in the open, and some under a leaf roof, and turned on the rain using NEI.

Good news is my leafroof works, odd news is the machines exposed to the rain did not explode, but they invariably lit on fire. They continued operating just fine while on fire though. Why did they not explode?

Comment: Water and lava drips under blocks are just aesthetic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie sometimes Greg can be a bit of a jerk on how literally he takes some things. TLDR: Never trust Greg. Be sure.

Comment: Working on the science for this as we speak. I'll probably dig through the configs as well, to see if there are any hints in there.

Comment: Good point. That's why I won't use GregTech anymore… especially since the whole sawmill/intentional crash debacle…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting consistent results that machines left in the rain or left on fire from a rainstorm will explode, given enough time.

[image: Figure 1: Raining, machine on fire.]

It's not instant; it can take a couple minutes. But eventually, your machine will blow up.

[image: Figure 2: Machine not on fire anymore (also not there anymore)]

I just tested this in peaceful mode, to see if there was any change, and it appears that difficulty has nothing to do with it. In fact, it doesn't even need to be powered. It still eventually caught fire and blew up.